# how to decide if a element is in a set in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

The situation is: I define a set in gams, like:

set n /n1*n100/;

And later in the code, I want to find a way to decide a if a element is in a set. For example, I want to have a function f, such that

(1) if a element in a set, it returns true(or '1'). Like, f('n1',n) = true(or '1')

(2) if a element not in a set, it returns false(or '0'). Like, f('n111',n) = false(or '0')

Does anyone know if there exists this kink of function? Also, if exists, does it also works for multiple dimensional set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear in what you want to do. That being said, **subsets** seem one to do what you want, for instance:

```
set m /n1*n100/;
set n(m) /n1*n50/;
parameter test(m);
test(m)=0;
test(n)=1;
display test;
```

This is overly explicit, for instance, you do not need `test(m)=0;` as gams default value is 0.

So that you could use `param(m)$test(m) = 3;` to only set the values where test is positive.
Of course, it is much simpler to use `param(n) = 3`

Finally, strictly speaking, the instructions: **`sameas(set1,set2)`** or **`sameas(set1,"n101")`** do what you want.

Without a clearer question, it is hard to help beyond this point.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I think my meaning is to use a function like 'sameas' to decide if an item is an element of an existing set.